# How can I implement a consumer producer where consumer can request fresh data

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Hy.

I'm not even sure how to form a title for this question.

Producer:
I have a case where I want to display some data on screen, but they need to be recalculated everytime users interacts with window. For click, drag or wheel event I send a signal that requests recalculation. So for rotation (drag event) tens of request may be emited. But if data is already being recalculated, procces must stop and restart. Recalculation can take from 10ms to 5s. Then using a semaphore/mutex I display some information under mouse cursor on hover event when data is ready.

Consumer:
Should receive request for recalculation and start recalculating. Should also stop any previous calculations. When calculation is over unlock mutex/semaphore.

I've been thinking and googling but am still unable to find a perfect solution for such problem. Can you point out to me some general solution that could work in this case.

Some facts about QT's signal&slot system that I think are relevant to this problem:
- when calculations are performed eventloop is not active thus slots are not executed until calculation is finished
- slots are executed one at a time

My solution was to use Consumer in main thread and Worker and Superviser both in own thread. But hopefully you can help me find better/cleaner solution.

Mitja

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to chunk up the calculation and have it processed in a timer event:

so if your current algo looks like

```
void MyObject::calculate()
{
    // data and state
    while(processing)
    {
        ///do some chunk of work
    }
    emit done(result);
}
```

it will become

```
// data and state in fields

void MyObject::calculate()
{
    if(!timerId)
        timerId = startTimer(0);//timeout of 0 means 

    //reset state and set data
}

void MyObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent* event)
{
    ///do some chunk of work

    if(done)
    {
        emit done(result);
        killTimer(timerId);
        timerId = 0;
    {
}
```

no need for semaphores because it all happens in the same event loop. You don't even need a separate thread for this because the event loop can remain running.